# Display video from Gridfs storage in react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, video, gridfs-stream

I am using `multer-gridfs-storage` and `gridfs-stream` to store my video in the backend (Express/Node). When I try to retrieve the file to play on my front end (React) the player refuses to recognize the source.

I am using Video-React to display the video on download. The download is successful, I get a Binary string back from the backend, which I converted to a Blob.

```
 try{
      fileBlob = new Blob([res.data], {type : res.headers['content-type']});
    }catch(err){
      console.log('Error converting to blob');
      console.log(err);
    }
```

This is my Video-React player being rendered

```
 <Player 
      autoPlay
      ref="player"
      >
      <source src={this.state.fileURL} />
      <ControlBar autoHide={false} />
      </Player>
```

Then I tried two techniques

1. `readDataAsURL`

   `let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event){
         //rThis is just a reference to the parent function this
         rThis.setState({fileURL: reader.result}, () => {
           rThis.refs.player.load();
         });
       }
       try{
         reader.readAsDataURL(fileBlob);
       }catch(err){
         console.log('Error trying readDataURL');
         console.log(err);
       }`

`src` is being set correctly but the video never loads

2. `URL.createObjectURL`

   `let vidURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob);
       rThis.setState({fileURL: vidURL}, () => {
       rThis.refs.player.load();
      });`

`src` is set to a `blob:` url but still nothing

Is this an issue with Video-react or should I be doing something else? Any pointers to references I could look at will also help. What am I doing wrong? dataURL works in the case of images, I checked, but not video.

Answer (score 0):

So after some more reading, I finally figured out the problem. Since I'm using `gridfs-stream` I'm actually piping the response from the server. So I was never getting the whole file, and trying to convert `res.data`, which is just a chunk, was a mistake. Instead, in my `res` object, I found the source url within the `config` property.

```
res.config.url
```

This contained my source url to which my server was piping the chunks. Should have figured it out earlier, considering I picked GridFS storage for precisely this reason.